# How do i get a value of attribute using the value of other attribute in same node ? XML XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

hi how do i can get the value of @ using other @ refferencing using XMLPath?

For example:

how do i get the value name of id 1?

ill select the attribute with id 1, but i would to get the value of name attribute, who returns "Camisa de Seda" something like: /items/item[@id="1"]@name (is this right?)

itemDb.xml:

```
<items>

<item id="0" name="Armadura de Couro">
    <attribute key="type" value="armadura"/>
    <attribute key="price" value="100"/>
</item>

<item id="1" name="Camisa de Seda">
    <attribute key="type" value="armadura"/>
    <attribute key="price" value="50"/>
</item> 

</items>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the value of the @Id attribute and you want to return the corresponding @name attribute value then the code you posted is almost correct, Try this one:

```
 //items/item[@id="1"]/@name
```