# How do I pull the value of a second attribute node within the same element node?

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I have an XML element with two attribute nodes, "key" and "value". I can navigate to the "key", but I'm trying to modify the "value". How can I do this?

Here is a snippet of the following XML document stored in the $XMLDoc variable:

```
<map>
                <entry key="star.debugMessages" value="false"/>
                <entry key="star.timeoutSecs" value="50"/>
                <entry key="star.loadBatchSize" value="10"/>
                <entry key="star.entity" value="Maven"/>
                <entry key="star.extractionRequestSize" value="30"/>
                <entry key="star.extractionSML" value="grabthisvalue"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
</map>
```

I have the following so far to reach the "star.extractionSML" attribute, but I want to modify its second attribute, "value":

```
$XMLDoc.map.entry.key[6]
```

From [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177432/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-attribute-using-the-value-of-other-attribute-in-same-nod), I tried the following which didn't work:

```
$XMLDoc.map.entry.key[6]/@value    
$XMLDoc.map.entry[@key="star.extractionSML"]/@value
```

It's a bit difficult for me to find what exactly I'm looking for and I'm not sure I'm explaining it well, but could someone point me in the right direction to jump from the "key" attribute to the "grabthisvalue" stored in the "value" attribute from the above XML document snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath to find the entry-node with the correct key. Ex:

```
$x.map.SelectSingleNode("entry[@key='star.extractionSML']").value
grabthisvalue

#or to modify it
$x.map.SelectSingleNode("entry[@key='star.extractionSML']").value = "newvalue"
$x.map.SelectSingleNode("entry[@key='star.extractionSML']").value
newvalue
```